# Displaying pages (containing charts) depending on the choice on first page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page in bootstrap framework. On the first page there is a carousel with 3 pictures directing to 3 pages,on every page there are bunch of charts. Those charts get their data from mysql and the query (static) is depended on the choice from the first page. 
3 Pictures with URL's:

```
Page_data_1.html
Page_data_2.html
Page_data_3.html
```

I would like to, somehow, make a parameter which will store the choice and remember it for queries (I was thinking of something like: `Page_data/?id=1` ...).

Then I could use this parameter and make query dynamic, depended on user choice from the first page.

How can I make this work?

Thanks

**EDIT :**

I made something like this:

#### Page1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head> 
  <body>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
        <a href="Page_data.php?id=1"><img src="img/a.png" alt="a"></a>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
        <a href="Page_data.php?id=2"><img src="img/b.png" alt="b"></a>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
        <a href="Page_data.php?id=3"><img src="img/c.png" alt="c"></a>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Page_data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<?php
session_start();
?>

</head>
<body>

<?php
echo 'Welcome to page Page_data.php?id='.$_SESSION['id'];
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**QUESTION**
How to insert id parameter into Page_data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP sessions for this.

Or if this query value convers only one page you can use parameter just like you said.

index.php?id=1
in code can be accessed

```
$_GET['id']
```

Comment: Does it require to make a cookie?

Comment: Sessions can be used also. They are of course cleared after browser close, of course cookie can be used also if choice have to 'live' longer.

Comment: So if I Have a vision of progress and have like 5 more pages: ColumnCharts.php, BarCharts.php, PieCharts.php; I should use sessions, instead of parameter? Is it possible to have something like this, after users choice: ColumnCharts.php?id=1, BartCharts.php?id=2.. etc. by sessions? And, by some "switcher" on every page jump from id1 to id2 without leaving the current page?

Comment: You can use $_SESSION and session variable will be visible on each of this pages.
But still you need to set/switch - to do it - you can use $_GET or $_POST - you will need to read more about those two methods, because those are basic ways to get data from user.

Comment: Can you look on my approach? I have edited my question. Please comment, thnks

Comment: In that case use - $_GET['id'], of course you can assign it then to $_SESSION['id'] if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience in bootstrap framework but in general you can have one page `Page_data.html` and in the code just use $_GET['id'] variable.

So your first page must point user to `/Page_data.html?id=1` instead `Page_data_1.html` after that.